# « Quoi faire » ou « que faire »… lequel est le plus correct?

Tags: pronoms, questions, québec, interrogative

J'ai toujours eu cette question: des fois j'ai vu ici au Québec (où j'habite) des pages internet qui utilisent « que faire » pour donner une procédure ou des indications à suivre pour une démarche X. Cependant, ne serait-ce pas plus correct de dire « quoi faire »? ou, est-ce qu'il y a certaines situations où l'usage de « que faire » est valide?

Comment: Il y a aussi _Comment faire_ de possible.

Answer (score 6):

Sans en apporter la preuve académique (d'autres feront cela mieux que moi), je dirais que, en France en tout cas, *que faire* est d'un niveau de plus soutenu que *quoi faire*. Autant je dirais facilement à l'oral *Je ne sais pas quoi faire...* (plutôt que le très formel, et un peu vieux-jeu *Je ne sais que faire...*), autant je trouverais bizarre de lire *Quoi faire en cas de ...?* en tête d'une liste, surtout dans un [contexte](http://vosdroits.service-public.fr/F10774.xhtml) [officiel](http://www.service-public.fr/professionnels-entreprises/actualites/00902.html).

Comment: Merci @Alexis Pigeon pour ta réponse et le lien d'exemple. Cependant, j'en ai encore le doute: si on visite le site web suivant [link](http://www.quoifaireaujourdhui.com/events/) on peut constater que l'article mentione "Quoi faire en cas de gastro?" et après ça donne des instructions ou plutôt des recommendations. Donc ma question revient... lequel est le bon usage? Aussi, on a par exemple [link](http://www.viarail.ca/fr/decouvrez-nos-destinations/gares/quebec/montreal/quoi-faire-a-montreal) ou on utilise "quoi" au lieu de "que".

Comment: et ceci a par nom [quoifaireaujourdhui.com](http://www.quoifaireaujourdhui.com/events/).

Comment: @AntonioMejia La conclusion est « quoi faire » est courant au Québec, alors que « que faire » est plus courant et plus soutenu en France (je confirme).

Comment: @AlexisPigeon: Appuyées sur votre réponse, les phrases : je ne sais pas quoi faire ≈ je ne sais que faire. Néanmoins, pourquoi pas je ne sais PAS que faire ? Je ne pige pas comment démêler [ je ne sais que faire ] de [je ne sais que faire = je sais seulement faire] ?

Answer (score 6):

Les pronoms interrogatifs *que* et *quoi* sont forts proches, ayant tout deux évolués à partir de *quid*.  Au sujet de leur utilisation comme complément essentiel direct de verbes à l'infinitif, Grevisse note que le pronom est *que* d'ordinaire ; *quoi* paraît d'une langue plus familière mais s'impose quand l'infinitif est introduit par une préposition (*Pour quoi faire ?*) et s'il y a un complément nominal avant l'infinitif (*Quoi sur la terre mettre en balance avec les joies d'un pareil moment ?*, Balzac)