# L'emploi de « que » ou « quoi » avec « faire »

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

On m'a appris qu'en général, on dit

> Que faire ?

et

> Je ne sais pas quoi faire.

Cependant, je lisais ce matin, et j'ai trouvé la phrase suivante (La nausée, "Lundi", vers page 82 selon l'édition):

> Devant le passage Gillet, je ne sais plus que faire.

Clairement, je ne pense pas que Sartre a fait une erreur de syntaxe, donc je me demande quelle règle permet l'usage de « que » ici. Est-ce que j'ai appris quelque chose d'incorrect ? Ou, s'agit-il d'une exception que je n'ai pas apprise ?

Comment: J'ai trouvé [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6335/358) après avoir répondu. J'ai cru d'abord à un doublon, mais après réflexion je n'en suis plus si sûre. La question de Derek Allums me semble plus spécifique.

Comment: Même chez Boris Vian, il faut un r : Jean-Sol Part**r**e (L'Écume des jours).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Je ne sais (plus) que faire* est correct et pas une originalité de Sartre. Quelques exemples choisis parmi ceux trouvés dans *Le bon usage*<sup>1</sup> :

> - La pauvre mère ne sait plus qu'inventer (Daudet)
> - Je ne savais plus que penser (P. Mac Orlan)
> - Ils ne savent qu'inventer sur nous, égoutiers (Giraudoux)

Voici ce que dit ***Le bon usage*** :

> [...] Dans l'interrogation indirecte, *que* s'emploie comme attribut ou complément d'objet direct après *avoir, savoir, pouvoir,* pris négativement et suivis d'un infinitif, parfois aussi après des verbes comme *chercher, se demander*, etc. suivis d'un infinitif.

Et en note :

> Dans l'usage ordinaire, et même dans la langue littéraire, *que*, ainsi employé, le cède de plus en plus à *quoi*, qui est plus étoffé, plus expressif : *Ne sachant quoi faire* (A. Gide). — *Je n'aurais pas su quoi répondre* (H. Bosco).  —  D'ailleurs *que*, dans certains cas, peut être équivoque ; par exemple : *Il ne sait que chercher* peut signifier : 1º il ne sait quelle chose chercher ; 2º il ne sait rien faire d'autre que chercher.  — Pour G. Gougenheim (*Études de gramm. et de vocabul. franç*., p. 124-29), le principe de différenciation entre *que* et *quoi* devant l'infinitif est la structure phonétique de l'expression ; *que* s'explique par l'attitude psychologique, et *quoi* par l'idée de la réalisation concrète. « Un homme qui se trouve dans une situation difficile exprimera son embarras en disant *Je ne sais que faire* ; un enfant qui s'ennuie dira *Je ne sais pas quoi faire*. »

***La grammaire Larousse du français contemporain***<sup>2</sup> disait la même chose en le formulant différemment :

> *Que* et *quoi* alternent quand la question porte sur l'objet direct d'un verbe à l'infinitif : *Le Saint-Père ne sait pas que faire, que dire, que penser* (Prévert). Alors, *quoi*  faire ? Je ne sais pas *quoi* faire.
> **Que** interroge plutôt sur l'action et **quoi**, de façon plus insistante, sur le contenu de l'action.

Quelques exemples trouvés dans la littérature contemporaine :

> Soudain, il essuie ses yeux pleins de larmes et je ne sais que faire. ([Jenifer Donaldson, ‎Pauline Vidal](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Je_sais_que_tu_te_souviens/eU-xDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22sais%20que%20faire%22&pg=PT13&printsec=frontcover))

> J'ai la tête en feu et je ne sais que faire, hormis confier mon CV au vendeur de marrons grillés ([Federica Bosco](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Il_y_a_toujours_un_lendemain/1wRGDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22sais%20que%20faire%22&pg=PT310&printsec=frontcover))

<sup><sup>1</sup>10e édition, 1975</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Jean-Claude Chevalier, Claire Blanche-Benveniste, Michel Arrivé et Jean Peytard, 1964.</sup>

---